# Excel look up value in array, return next value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup-tables

I would like to look up a value in a range and return the value in the next row, but can't quite figure out how to do this. I especially would like to do this with formulas rather than VBA, and preferably with built-in formulas than custom (VBA) formulas, due to macro security issues.

I'm using Excel 2010. My workbook has two worksheets, "assessment" and "lookup". In lookup, I have lookup tables.

"lookup" looks something like:

```
  Column A Column B     Column C
1 Sales    Engineering  Manufacturing
2 Alice    Bobbie       Charlie
3 Dawn     Edgar        Frank
4 George   Holly        Isabel
```

In "assessment," I have some some drop downs from which users select one name from each column in "lookup." Based on some other criteria, I then rank these and create a new, sorted list (using `INDEX()` and `MATCH()`) that produce the selected name and corresponding column name a new sort order

```
   Column A    Column B
10 Engineering Edgar
11 Sales       Alice
```

What I'd like is to return the name from the next row.

```
   Column C 
10 Holly
11 Dawn
```

But I'm having real trouble figuring out how to get there.

Comment: What is the formula you are using now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming lookups is located at `B2:D5` *(change as required)* and the result data is at `F2:H3` *(change as required)* enter this formula in cell `H2` then copy down.

```
=INDEX(
INDEX($B$2:$D$5,0,MATCH($F2,$B$2:$D$2,0)),
1+MATCH($G2,
INDEX($B$2:$D$5,0,MATCH($F2,$B$2:$D$2,0)),0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks; that's what I needed. I'm finding that the results are more robust if the second MATCH() statement is also set to exact match (adding in the third argument).

Comment: Sorry, I missed that zero, must of the times the intent is to obtain absolute match. Thanks for the correction. I'm applying the correction...